# How to stop fixed/floating div at a specific point

Tags: jquery, position, fixed

I realize there are many questions similar to mine on this site, but because their original code is so different than mine, I have not been able to use their solutions though I tried a million different ways.

I'd like to make this green box stop at a certain point. It behaves exactly like I want it to minus covering the hbar at thebottom and the words stop/post. I'd like it to stop much higher than this at a point that I chose.

Please see my demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kachish/RqELN/1/

Below is the Javascript and CSS:

**Javascript:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        var useFixedSidebar = $(document).scrollTop() > 150;
        $('.important').toggleClass('fixedSidebar', useFixedSidebar);
    });

</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fixedSidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}
```

​

Comment: Is the `div.important` height supposed to be 600px until it gets to the bottom where the horizontal bar and stop/post words appear? If so, is the `<hr>` the element where the `div.important` should stop?

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your response. Yes the div.important box will always be 600px. And yes, basically I'd like for it to stop itself above the <hr> and then roll out of the screen naturally if I continued to scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y6xPC/) based on yours.

JQuery:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
    var scrollVal = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.important').css('top',scrollVal+'px');
    if (scrollVal < 150) { 
        $('.important').css('top','100px');
    }
    if (scrollVal > 1347) {
        $('.important').css('top','1111px');    
    }
});​
```

CSS:

```
.important { 
    position: absolute;
}
```

​

Comment: I have some tweaking to do but this is exactly what I wanted to accomplish, thanks Peter!!!!!!!

Comment: There are a couple of syntax points if the above is a direct paste. You have two `}`s at the end of the CSS. and `<script src="code. ...` should be `<script src="http://code. ...` You don't need the `;` after the first closing script tag. Also the position values (150, 100, 1347, 1111) may need adjusting for your page. Those are the values for the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Peter again seriously. If you're still there I have yet another question. I'm able to get everything to work as in fiddle but it seems the problem with my normal page is I have replaced the img with javascript and then no longer works at all. Any idea why this would be? The added javascript itself functions normally on the page but it does not scroll anymore 
<div id="important"><img></div> Works 
<div id="important"><javascscript></div> Does not work

Comment: I can take a look at it. Update your fiddle and let me know.